# git-python get commit feed from a repository

Tags: python, git

am working on a code which I would like to retrieve the commits from a repository on github. Am not entirely sure how to do such a thing, I got git-python but most the api's are for opening a local git repository on the same file system.

Can someone advice?

regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the easiest thing here is to use the commandline (I'm assuming Linux or any other Unix here, but should be the same on Windows) to clone an existing repository first:

git clone git://github.com/forsberg/misctools.git

This will create the `misctools` directory.

Now, from python, you can open this repository and update it using pull:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from git import *

repo = Repo("misctools")
o = repo.remotes.origin
o.pull()

master = repo.head.reference
print master.log()
```

It's all documented at http://packages.python.org/GitPython/0.3.2/tutorial.html

Comment: With newer version of GitPython you can clone the remote repository using the command: `Repo.clone_from("https://github.com/forsberg/misctools.git", "local_path")`.

Answer (score 21):

For me the following worked best:

Imports:

```
import os
import datetime
import git
```

Get current repository, assuming that you're there:

```
repo = git.Repo(os.getcwd())
```

Get active branch:

```
master = repo.head.reference
```

Current branch:

```
master.name
```

Latest commit id:

```
master.commit.hexsha
```

Latest commit message:

```
master.commit.message
```

Latest commit date:

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(master.commit.committed_date)
```

Latest commit author email:

```
master.commit.author.email
```

Latest commit author name:

```
master.commit.author.name
```

Answer (score 1):

I really advise using only the command line git, git-python its used for macros or complicated things, not just for pulling, pushing or cloning :)

Answer (score 0):

If that's what you're after, I have a bash script to send myself emails about the latest git commits. It runs as a cronjob.

https://github.com/martinxyz/config/blob/master/scripts/email-git-commit-summary.sh