# Questions about the text parsing

Tags: python

I want to parse the info from the git commit logs , the data format is as follows ( each commit is belonged to one repo , and each repo may contains several commits )

How can I get each part info (commit , Author , Date...) and save to the dict like the picture below ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUTtJ.png

Could anyone help me there ? Many thanks

```
repo:device/sprd

commit 775ffdbcbd3e506b38fc5b57debc181e57d52654

Author: zhijie.yang <zhijie.yang@spreadtrum.com>

Date:   Sun Feb 21 13:33:53 2016 +0800

Bug #532015 [new feature] EngineerMode add a SethRps switch

[root cause  ] new features
[changes     ] let EngineerMode can to write to /sys/class/net/seth_lte0/queues/rx-0/rps_cpus
[side effects] no
[self test   ] <9832><follow bug steps,test 5 times,pass>
[reviewers   ] jing.deng
[change_type ] feature
[tag_product ] common

Change-Id: Icaa1e5ec8f3eea7b7912bf59595e4b0884bf65e3

scx35l/init.sc8830_base.rc |   18 ++++++++++++++++++

1 file changed, 18 insertions(+)

repo:kernel

commit fc82a44b8965994fa2340832770169ce0242656f

Author: daniel.li <daniel.li@spreadtrum.com>

Date:   Mon Feb 22 19:02:45 2016 +0800

Bug #524747  add otg function for sp9832a board

[root cause  ] add  otg function for iea board
[changes     ] arch/arm/boot/dts/
[change_type ] bringup --> sprd_chip_support
[tag_product ] common
[side effects] no
[self test   ] <sp9832a><adb pull/push ok, USB keypad OK>
[reviewers   ] fei.zhang

Change-Id: Ie054e5e3c9c4c770a40eccf4b43500a666663023

.../boot/dts/sprd-scx35l_sp9832a_3h10_5mvolte.dts  |    6 +++---
arch/arm/configs/sp9832a_3h10_5mvolte_defconfig    |    6 +++---

2 files changed, 6 insertions(+), 6 deletions(-)

commit 35450fb6f5720b1f84698fc80d9df28035725a9d

Author: zhijie.yang <zhijie.yang@spreadtrum.com>

Date:   Sun Feb 21 15:31:38 2016 +0800

Bug #532015 [new feature] EngineerMode add a SethRps switch

[root cause  ] new features
[changes     ] EngineerMode add a SethRps switch
[side effects] no
[self test   ] <9832><follow bug steps,test 5 times,pass>
[reviewers   ] jing.deng
[change_type ] feature
[tag_product ] common

Change-Id: I6fe8bb0e158617d8e1efefaed3b6d53b43eeef5e

res/values/strings.xml                             |    1 +
res/xml/pref_telephonytab.xml                      |    4 ++++
.../sprd/engineermode/BootCompletedReceiver.java   |    1 +
.../engineermode/telephony/TelephonyFragment.java  |   21 ++++++++++++++++++++

4 files changed, 27 insertions(+)

repo:vendor/sprd/modules/libcamera

commit 53ce0f9adcaeefa84f49ab49703ea3ed7463b980

Author: zhijie.yang <zhijie.yang@spreadtrum.com>

Date:   Fri Feb 5 15:44:22 2016 +0800

Bug #524747 - [new feature] EngineerMode add a SethRps switch

[root cause  ] new features
[changes     ] EngineerMode add a SethRps switch
[side effects] no
[self test   ] <9832><follow bug steps,test 5 times,pass>
[reviewers   ] jing.deng
[change_type ] feature
[tag_product ] common

Change-Id: I173fe4e54d349ecc41200b72948cea8b02740e23

.../sp9832a_3h10_5mvolte/pinmap-sp9630-h100.c      |    6 +++---

1 file changed, 3 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Python has libraries for talking to git; I wouldn't try parsing text.

Comment: I'm novice of python and had wrote some simple codes to parse the text , but the codes were not very satisfactory , so I am very grateful if any simple  codes or libraries can do this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git-python get commit feed from a repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806266/git-python-get-commit-feed-from-a-repository)

Comment: Many thanks , it was what I want :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say skip parsing the raw text format.
For starters it's messy as anything and the second reason would be that it's way harder than getting a pre-formatted structure from a library that supports git.

Try for instance the [git](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GitPython/) module:

```
from git import *

repo = Repo("sprd")
o = repo.remotes.origin
o.pull()

master = repo.head.reference
print master.log()
```

Also give credit where credit is due: [git-python get commit feed from a repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806266/git-python-get-commit-feed-from-a-repository)

Comment: thanks a lot , I will study the GitPython farther , it is a very useful module for git :)

Comment: @JiangLing You're welcome. Welcome to SO and if you feel that any answer solves your question, please mark them as answered (mine or others) so we don't keep answered questions open in vain. Thank you and good luck with your project!