# python script to print the last commit message from specific git branch

Tags: python, python-3.x, github-api, pygithub

```
from github import Github
import sys
import requests
import subprocess
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
# github connection
gc = Github(login_or_token = '3d09afd6df8d92bd', password = None, b 
base_url = "https://eos2git.com/api/v3", timeout = 60, verify=False, retry=5)
# enter github repo
repo_gh = gc.get_repo('Devops/emporium')
# get the branches of the given repo
branches = repo_gh.get_branches()
for branch in branches:

    if branch.name == "dev/anjali-raghu/DSE-401":
        # print the last commit message of a branch 
        print(branch.commit)
```

But the print(branch.commit) print the commit SHA i.e, Commit(sha="026493bb65bc12c99f66c159eda050471d6757ff") instead of commit message.
Could you please help me to print the last commit message of a specific branch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git-python get commit feed from a repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806266/git-python-get-commit-feed-from-a-repository)

Comment: https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/issues/2261

Comment: @AlexisG The question is about PyGithub accessing a remote repository hosted at GitHub. No local repo, no GitPython.

Comment: github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/issues/2261 this works for me Thanks :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read in the [documentation for PyGitHub](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/GitCommit.html#gitcommit), GitCommit objects contain `.message` attribute with the data you need. `Commit` objects contain corresponding GitCommit object in `.commit` attribute.
Thus you can access the data you need with `branch.commit.commit.message`

Comment: Using "branch.commit.commit.message" i am getting all commit message but I want the lastest commit message